# For $a,b \in \sum_2$, prove $ab \in \sum_2$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-verification, sums-of-squares

I believe this is a basic proof but just hoping someone could give me some feedback on my attempt.

$\sum_2:=\{x^2+y^2 | x,y \in \mathbb{Z}\}$

Since $a,b \in \sum_2$ it follows:

$a=u^2+v^2$

$b=n^2+m^2$   $\qquad$   (For $m,n,u,v \in \mathbb{Z}$)

$ab=(u^2+v^2)(n^2+m^2)=u^2n^2+u^2m^2+v^2n^2+v^2m^2$

This can be rewritten as: $ab= (un)^2+(um)^2+(vn)^2+(vm)^2$

We can see $(un)^2+(um)^2 \in \sum_2$ and $(vn)^2+(vm)^2 \in \sum_2$

Is this enough to conclude that $ab \in \sum_2$? The question is not worth many marks so I feel a small proof is all that is needed but this feels incomplete to me.

I'd appreciate any insights!

Comment: "We can see $(un)^2+(um)^2 \in \sum_2$ and $(vn)^2+(vm)^2 \in \sum_2$" - why?

Comment: In the definition of $\Sigma_2,$ the set after $x,y \in$ should not be $\Sigma_2$ again, but something else.

Comment: No. $\Sigma_2$ is not closed under addition. You need to use the identity that expresses that the absolute value of a product of two complex numbers is the product of the absolute values of the factors. IIRC an ancient Indian scholar (Brahmagupta?) is often credited for having come up with it.

Comment: Hint: Expand
$$(un-vm)^2+(um+vn)^2.$$

Comment: If a sum of 2 sums of 2 squares were always a sum of 2 squares then so would be every number. Including 3.

Comment: $(un)^2 + (um)^2 + (vn)^2 + (vm)^2$ does not imply this term is in $\Sigma_2$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Saying $ab = S + T$ where $S = (un)^2 + (um)^2 \in \Sigma_2$ and $T = (vn)^2 + (vm)^2 \in \Sigma_2$ *would* be enough to conclude that $ab \in \Sigma_2$ *only if* you had shown that $\Sigma_2$ is closed under addition. This is not the case.

Instead what you want to do is think of this in terms of complex numbers. If $u, v \in \mathbb Z$ then define $N(u + iv) = u^2 + v^2$. It is a basic fact of complex arithmetic that $N(z)N(z') = N(zz')$ where $z, z'$ are complex. How do we apply this here? Well,

$$(u^2 + v^2)(m^2 + n^2) = N(u + vi)N(m + ni) = N((u + vi)(m + ni)) $$

and we have

$$ (u + vi)(m + ni) = (um - vn) + (un + vm)i $$

so

$$ (u^2 + v^2)(m^2 + n^2) = (um - vn)^2 + (un + vm)^2. $$

You should expand both sides to verify this.